# Read first bit of a number in one line

Tags: c++, c++11, bit-manipulation, bit

I have a number and I just want to read the first bit of the number. I do it like below

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char*argv[]) {

    unsigned int number = 12345;    // Some number   
    int bit_number_to_read = 1;
    int mask =  1 << bit_number_to_read;
    int masked_n = number & mask;
    unsigned int the_bit = masked_n >> bit_number;
    std::cout << "The first bit of number contains: " << the_bit << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The above technique works but is it possible to do it in a one liner?

Comment: That's the second bit. Do you want least significant bit (LSB) or most significant bit (MSB)?

Comment: Oh. I am not even reading the first bit

Comment: `0x1 & number` should get me the first bit. Right? Or am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, it will be the least significant bit.

Comment: If it's odd the bit is 1 if it's even the bit is 0.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to get least significant bit is to check if number is even (only works with non-negative numbers):

```
int LSB = number % 2;
```

If you want to use bitwise operators to be more verbose:

```
int MSB = number & 1;
```

Or (maybe even overly verbose, but conveys the meaning "I want bit at position 0"):

```
int MSB = number & (1 << 0);
```

---

To get most significant bit, you need to first learn what is the number of digits in given type representation:

```
int digits = std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::digits();
int MSB = number & (1 << (digits - 1))
```

Note that for signed types this will provide the most significant number bit (ignoring sign bit).

Comment: My number will not be negative. Thats why I have unsigned int type for `number`

Answer (score 3):

If it's odd the bit is `1` if it's even the bit is `0`.

So you could do somenthing like:

```
unsigned int the_bit = number % 2;
```

---

If you were considering the possibility of also having negative `int`s:

```
unsigned int the_bit = std::llabs(number % 2);
```

`llabs` because in some machines `long` is `32` bits whereas `long long` has to be at least `64` bits.

This is valid for 2's complement.

---

Or of course the bitwise `AND`.

```
 unsigned int the_bit = number & 1;
```

Simple and effective, `1 AND 1` is `1`, `0 AND 1` is `0`.

Comment: is it possible to avoid the odd even checking? Its always going to be unsigned int 16 bits number. I just want to read the first bit to see whether it is set or or set. Thats it. Simple!

Comment: @DarkMatter_Programmer, even though you could read the 1st bit, it's not very effective, because the bool type in C is just an alias for a bigger type, usually int, so I think this is the cleanest way. `0x1` is still an `int` for the compiler.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't check carefully if your code is correct. However, writing it in a single line can be just an exercise of replacing equivalent expressions:

```
unsigned int number = 12346;    // Some number   
int bit_number_to_read = 1;
int mask =  1 << bit_number_to_read;
int masked_n = number & mask;
unsigned int the_bit = masked_n >> bit_number_to_read;
std::cout << "The first bit of number contains: " << the_bit << std::endl;

std::cout << (masked_n >> bit_number_to_read) << "\n";
std::cout << ( (number&mask) >> bit_number_to_read) << "\n";
std::cout << ( (number&(1 << bit_number_to_read)) >> bit_number_to_read) << "\n";
```

All the `cout`s will print the same result. As you already mentioned in a comment, the first bit you also get via `0x1 & number`.

Comment: `(number&(1 << bit_number_to_read)) >> bit_number_to_read)` seems to be the way. Thanks. One of the comments deleted said that `>> bit_number_to_read` is not needed? Why is that?